Rescale measures of association for meta-analysis (e.g., log-transformed independent variables)
I am carrying out a meta-analysis of studies evaluating the association between blood levels of specific environmental pollutants and health outcomes (binary).
Some studies reported OR/RR/HR for continuous independent variables with different units (e.g., for a 1-unit increase, for a 10-unit increase), while others reported OR/RR/HR for log- or log(2)-transformed independent variables.
While I know how to convert OR/RR/HR to different units for independent variables that are not log-transformed (e.g., from a 1-unit increase to a 10-unit increase), I am having a hard time with studies that used log-transformation.
Any ideas on how to get all these results on the same scale (either log-transformed or not)? I would need this both for the point estimate and the confidence interval (or standard error). Since this is a meta-analysis, I do not have access to the original individual-level data from the included studies.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I fear that what you want to do requires the original data.

I agree with @NickCox. The only option is to do two separate meta-analyses, one for linear and one for log.

Assuming that information about the mean value (point estimate?) and variance is available in the original study, a back-transformation from the log-scale to the original scale should be feasible, if I understand the question right.
I have little experience with OR/RR/HR, but for variables following a normal distribution, the transformation using log (base e) in both directions is defined on several sites (e.g. Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution). If this hasn't been defined for the specific distribution, something similar could be done using Taylor-expansions.
